# Returning multiple "SUM" columns with knex for node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

I am able to return one column of "SUM" in knex, but how can I return two columns with "SUM"?

The line below works to return one column of "SUM":

```
knex.select('username',db.raw('SUM(units)')).from('my_table').groupByRaw('username')


RESULT 
{ 
  username: 'John", 
  sum: '125' 
}
```

However, I want to return something like this :

```
{
 username "John",    
 sumUnits: '125' ,    
 sumCases:'321' 
}
```

So I tried the code below but it just returns an error, is it possible to have two "SUM" columns with knex ?

```
knex.select('username', db.raw('SUM(units)'), db.raw('SUM(cases)') ).from('my_table').groupByRaw('username')
```

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it !

Here is the solution in case anyone else needs it .

```
knex('my_table')
  .select('username')
  .sum({ total_units: 'units', total_cases: 'cases' })
  .groupBy('username')
```

translates to :

```
SELECT 
username, 
SUM(units) as total_units, 
SUM(cases) as total_cases 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY username;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return knex('test_score').columns([
    knex.raw('sum(first_round + second_round + third_round) as max_val')
  ])
```

this can work

Comment: @Komakino_1251 please reply to this answer.